# Separate documents by string field into arrays in mongodb

Tags: json, database, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have some documents as such:

```
{
    product: "product1",
    version: "1.5"
    uri: "http://...",
    created: "dateisastringpleasedontask",
    ...
}
```

And I would like to run a query that separates by data by product, then version internally. sort of like this:

```
{
    "product1": [
        "1.0": [ {..}, {..} ],
        "1.5": [ {..} ]
    ],
    "product2": [
        "2.0": [ {..} ]
    ]
}
```

Or something to that effect so that I can drill down via product first, then version underneath.

I'm trying to achieve this using aggregation in a one query operation, so would be even better if this can be achieved as such.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below aggregation query. `$$ROOT` to access the whole document rest is the group to create product-version level structure.

```
db.colname.aggregate([
  {"$group":{
    "_id":{"product":"$product","version":"$version"},
    "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {"$group":{
    "_id":"$_id.product",
    "all":{"$push":{"version":"$_id.version","data":"$data"}}
  }}
])
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to verify answer ? Let me know if something is missing.